# Email Sending in Servlet using form post method

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, servlet-3.0

I want to send mail through form post method but I'm getting

> HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error
>
> Execption: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Note: I have installed libraries: `javax.mail.jar` and `activation.jar`

In my `Mail.jsp` page

```
<form action="ServlateMail" method="post">
    To:<input type="text" name="to"  /><br/>
    Subject:<input type="text" name="subject"  /><br/>
    Message:<input type="text" name="message"  /><br/>
    Your Email id:<input type="text" name="user" ><br/>
    Password<;input type="password" name="pass"   /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

In my `ServlateMail`:

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import utils.Sendmail;


public class ServletMail extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
  response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset-UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String to = request.getParameter("to");
    String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
    String message =  request.getParameter("message");
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    Sendmail.sendmailer(to,subject, message, user, pass);
    System.out.println("Mail send successfully");
}   
}
```

In my java class:

```
package utils;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class Sendmail 
  { 
  public static void sendmailer(String to, String sub, 
                     String msg, final String user,final String pass)
  { 
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
 props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");        
 props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
 props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator()
{
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
  {
     return new PasswordAuthentication(user,pass);
  }
}); 
 try
  {

   MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
   message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
   message.setSubject(sub);
   System.out.print("testing");
   message.setText(msg);
   Transport.send(message);


   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }  
 }
```

Comment: We need to know what exception was thrown during servlet execution.  The details may be attached to the ServletException as the "cause", or they may be in your server's log file.

Comment: did you add java mail dependency/add jar? another thing is you need to make gmail account less secure.